# SharePoint Framework 1.6 MSGraphClient Error

Tags: sharepoint-framework

I receive the following error trying to call Microsoft Graph using MSGraphClient in a new SharePoint Framework 1.6 Web Part.

> The requested operation is part of an experimental feature that is not supported in the current environment.

If this message is valid, how can I find out when this feature will be supported?  Otherwise, is there a workaround or fix for it?

These are the directions I followed to make the graph call: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-msgraph

I was able to fix the problem in a dev tenant by running the Enable-SPOTenantServicePrincipal command in SharePoint Online Powershell, and giving SharePoint Online Client Extensibility "Sign in and read user profile" permission to Windows Azure Active Directory through the Azure AD Portal.

However, I do not have the same permissions in my company's production tenant and am unable to run the Enable-SPOTenantServicePrincipal command.  It will be hard to make the case to the production tenant admin to run it either when the documentation says "This is a preview feature and should not be used in production."

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/enable-spotenantserviceprincipal

Is this still a preview feature, or is the documentation just outdated?  The Release Notes for SPFx 1.6 make it sound like using the MSGraphClient is mandatory.

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/wiki/SharePoint-Framework-v1.6-release-notes

Comment: Please checkout this post [You might experience errors when first trying new SPFx 1.6 features](http://spblog.net/post/2018/09/19/You-might-experience-errors-when-first-trying-new-SPFx-16-features)